# Alt Gr not working with Microsoft Windows RDP client on Mac OS with a PC keyboaard

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop

Alt Gr key (right alt) randomly stops working when working on Microsoft RDP client and behaves as left alt instead.

I am on a Macbook Air M1, with a PC keyboard, using an AzertyPC layout in MacOS.

When this occurs, switching the RDP keyboard mode to Unicode will fix the problem but it will create other issues (like shift+leftAlt+key will stop working in visual studio inside the RDP)

This leads to three questions:

1. There is a workaround on windows for this issue which is to press ALT+Enter on a RDP window. Is there an explanation on what it does? Is there a smilar workaround on MacOS?
2. Why switching to Unicode makes Alt Gr work properly?
3. Why in Unicode Shift+LeftAlt+Key works differently?

Comment: Mac has no idea what alt/gr is [nor does it by default differentiate between the left & right Ctrl keys at all]. Try the two distinct keys that make up alt/gr, Ctrl + Opt[alt].

Comment: The keyboard has a PC layout and macOS keyboard is set to Azerty PC. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it stops working. There is a workaround which is press alt+enter but it does not seem to work on mac. Using Ctrl+Opt does work but it's annoying

Comment: The Mac simply doesn't respond to an alt/gr key. It's entirely a 1980s unix construct, which Windows adopted & translated into ctrl+alt. It has no meaning on Mac, whatever your keyboard layout is set to. The Mac will register that key as just alt/opt whether you're set to a Mac or PC keyboard layout. I just tested.

Comment: today when I restarted the RDP it started working again. Clearly macOS is able to differentiate Alt and AltGr when sending the keystroke to MS RDP. I am not sure what you're trying to demonstrate but this is not really helpful.

Comment: Then RDP must be recognising it specifically. macOS doesn't. It never has. I actually went to find a Mac with a PC keyboard to test it. If that's not helpful, I'l stop trying to help.

Comment: sorry my issue is that this key randomly stops working on the RDP and I'd just like to understand what to do to fix it when it occurs. I know that ALT+Enter will work on Windows but it doesn't help in MacOS. I get what you say. Thank you. I already upvoted your first comment. It seems you are implying that MacOS might be transforming the AltGr key to Alt before it reaches the RDP, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The key does generate a different code which something must be recognising specifically. The Mac technically can tell the difference between any left/right alt, ctrl, cmd too, but usually doesn't actively differentiate. This image is key down, key up for all mod keys left to right... ctrl, win, alt, alt/gr, ctrl - https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3xho.png Note it doesn't specifically recognise alt/gr, it's just 'right alt'

Comment: yes it makes sense. I'll edit the question to make it more clear as this has nothing to do with my issue

Comment: To complete the data set I re-did the keycodes test on an Apple keyboard - they are identical, so it's definitely recognising alt/gr as 'right alt'; that's going to make it something specifically in RDP that's misbehaving. Testing RDP here it does recognise right alt as alt/gr [viewing it on the Windows on-screen keyboard]

Comment: Thank you. I just edited the question and breaked it down in 3 points I'd like to understand.

Comment: One thing worth a shot is to get the RDC beta from https://install.appcenter.ms/orgs/rdmacios-k2vy/apps/microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac/distribution_groups/all-users-of-microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac - [this is the legitimate MS download site] It includes a bug reporting framework & I've known MS get back within a day to request further info on a report, so they are definitely paying attention.

Comment: Have exactly the same issue with a Mac host and RDP. Shitf+LeftAlt is extactly the same as AltGr - so randomly not working. Any substitute keys for AltGr which work in MacOS do not work in most of the Windows apps as those are already reserved keymaps. Unbelievable, that this extremely annoying issue has no solution.

Comment: @clementino - Well, the workaround, right from the opening comment, is to use Ctrl/Opt. All Windows does is combine those two modifiers into a single key.

Comment: @Tetsujin unfortunately this does not work for me. Pressing Ctrl/Opt + any other key is executing some commands in the software I'm using (IDEs), because those are reserved key shortcuts. I could delete those from the IDE but then I don't have those shortcuts.

Comment: In my case the issue when pressing alt is moving the cursor left everytime I press AltGr, so I've arrived to the same stack level issue, macos or RDP is not processing the key correctly. (azerty MBP)